# How to rewrite file extention sitemap.php to sitemap.xml in cakephp website?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I have a cakephp website and I have located sitemap.php in webroot folder.
I want to rewrite its url in .htaccess file to sitemap.xml
but normal php techniques are not working.
I tried using the following.

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ xmlsitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap$ sitemap.php [L]
```

but it doesnot work in cakephp.
Any idea how to do this? Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you not directly using sitemap.xml to display your XML sitemap?

Comment: Could you please edit your question with your entire htaccess code ? Also, where is `webroot` located compared to your root directory ?

Answer (score 0):

The only file that should be loaded in the webroot directory should be the index.php. Your application should handle the routing from that point. To customize your routes look at the routes.php files in the Config folder.

Have a look at the routing docs.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

For cake you want to use the default automagic routes as much as possible. 
For example:
/my_widgets/create would map to the MyWdigetsController and the action create()

I would suggest moving whatever functionality you have in your sitemap.php and move it into an existing controller action. You can also use the parseExtensions feature of cake to give you the proper header and load the correct file for you.

Example for getting /sitemap.xml to load your xml sitemap.

In your routes.php

```
Router::connect(
    '/sitemap.xml',
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'sitemap', 'ext'=>'xml')
);

Router::parseExtensions('xml');
```

In your PagesController create an action called sitemap. Put whatever code generates your sitemap data in that action.

In your Views/Pages directory create a folder called xml and place a file called sitemap.ctp

In that file place your output for the xml.

**I have had problems before if debug is set above 0 so if you do not see any output, try setting debug level to 0**

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitemap.xml
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.php$ - [L]
```